# Complex table with \multicolumn

Tags: tables

The layout that I need to implement inside Latex is this (made with M.word)[image]

I tried to make this layout
Here is my Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}||p{12cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ligula ligula, tristique vel consectetur et, cursus eget ante. Sed sed vulputate magna, nec imperdiet sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam faucibus pellentesque rhoncus. Aenean rhoncus, nibh vitae vestibulum pharetra, quam elit aliquam tellus, ut ultricies lacus purus nec felis. Cras in convallis risus, ac consectetur nulla. Proin enim justo, volutpat ac tortor nec, tempus bibendum felis. Suspendisse commodo mi eget mauris molestie condimentum. Donec egestas quis mauris ut viverra. Nunc egestas diam nisi, elementum efficitur tortor suscipit ut. Donec lobortis risus et leo mollis feugiat. Donec gravida enim sit amet fringilla rutrum. Nullam bibendum lacinia lacus, a hendrerit dolor convallis vitae. } \\

\hline
Option 1: & \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{itemize}

\\
\hline
Option 2: & \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}
```

I have some difficulties :

1. The "A- Paragraph title":  it's a subtitle that is followed by a paragraph.
2. The long paragraph in the first line, goes outside  the table.
3. I don't know how to make "Option 1" and "Option 2" oriented vertically

Results Obtained :

[image]

This layout will be repeated for many rows, one Line with one column and 4 lines with 2 columns and so on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `p{<length>}` spec inside the argument of `\multicolumn` if you want line breaks.  I suggest you use `tabularx` right away.  Reg. making "Option 1" and "Option 2" oriented vertically: It is ugly and hard to read.  My recommendation is just don't do it.  Other thing you probably want is to reduce the vertical spacing around itemize.  Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,lipsum,enumitem}

\newcommand{\tablistcmd}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *           ,
  label      = \textbullet ,
  nosep                    ,
  before     = \tablistcmd ,
  after      = \tablistcmd
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{%
    \textbf{A-Paragraph title:} \lipsum*[1]
  } \\ \midrule
  Option 1: & 
              \begin{tabitemize}
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \end{tabitemize} \\ \midrule
  Option 2: & 
              \begin{tabitemize}
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              \end{tabitemize}  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `tabularx` and `hhline`, to improve the look of your word table. I customised the spacings in the `itemize` environment with the `enumitem` package:

```
     \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{fourier}

 \usepackage{tabularx,array, rotating, caption, hhline}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}
\setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=-2pt, topsep=3pt, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip + \topsep}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering}p{2cm}||X| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{%
\textbf{A – Paragraph title}\smallskip\par
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ligula ligula, tristique vel consectetur et, cursus eget ante. Sed sed vulputate magna, nec imperdiet sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam faucibus pellentesque rhoncus. Aenean rhoncus, nibh vitae vestibulum pharetra, quam elit aliquam tellus, ut ultricies lacus purus nec felis. Cras in convallis risus, ac consectetur nulla. Proin enim justo, volutpat ac tortor nec, tempus bibendum felis. Suspendisse commodo mi eget mauris molestie condimentum. Donec egestas quis mauris ut viverra. Nunc egestas diam nisi, elementum efficitur tortor suscipit ut. Donec lobortis risus et leo mollis feugiat. Donec gravida enim sit amet fringilla rutrum. Nullam bibendum lacinia lacus, a hendrerit dolor convallis vitae. } \\
\hhline{=t:t:=}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Option 1} & \begin{itemize}[]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ligula ligula, tristique vel consectetur et, cursus eget ante. \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{itemize}
\\
\hhline{=::=}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Option 2} & \begin{itemize}[wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=-2pt, topsep =2pt]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{itemize}\\
\hhline{-||-}
\end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]